# bash script: if condition not working as expected on AWS lambda container image

Tags: bash, aws-lambda-containers

I've a lambda function which uses container image(Docker) and the main function is written in `bash`. I am facing issue in my conditional logic:

```
if [[ $cur_cert == *"ca-cert"* ]]; then
      echo "CA-CERT"
    elif [[ $cur_cert == *"ssl-cert"* && $cur_cert == *"public"* ]]; then
      echo "SSL-CERT-PUBLIC"
    elif [[ $cur_cert == *"ssl-cert"* && $cur_cert == *"private"* ]]; then
      echo "SSL-CERT-PRIVATE"
    fi
```

This script is working perfectly fine on my local system. But on lambda it is not executing the code block under if/else even if the conditions are matching.

I'm using ubuntu as the base image for my Docker container. (`FROM ubuntu`)

Comment: Is it actually running under bash, or some other shell? The `[[ ]]` conditional syntax is nonstandard, and not all shells support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a POSIX shell grammar rather than Bash dialect, ensures better compatibility with other shell interpreters:

```bash
case $cur_cert in
*ca-cert*) printf %s\\n CA-CERT ;;
*ssl-cert*) case $cur_cert in
  *public*) printf %s\\n SSL-CERT-PUBLIC ;;
  *private*) printf %s\\n SSL-CERT-PRIVATE ;;
  esac ;;
esac
```

Comment: What about other comparators (like -gt -lt etc..)?